# Matlab stdout and stderr?

Tags: java, matlab, stdout, stderr, matlab-java

I can create standard output and standard error in Matlab using:

```
fprintf(1, "This is output"); and
fprintf(2, "This is an error");
```

Question: How can I collect those logs (streams) from Matlab using Java without saving them in an intermidiate log file?

Comment: In fact I dont have experience with Java. I just want to make sure that what i am saying makes sense. For the moment I am just working with matlab. I already read about pipes but I am not sure if there exists an implimentation of that for matlab-java interface.
Anyways thank you for your comment @billc.cn

Comment: I have never tried something like that, but you might want to consider  [`MatlabControl`](https://github.com/diffplug/matconsolectl).